# VB.Net - Resources folder is found as a virus for others

Tags: vb.net, resources, antivirus

As an installer developer... There are a few thousand people who use my software, I have to try my best to get the people to keep using my installer.

Everything was going well up until last month.

I spoke to some people who have this problem / error this is what the error says:

http://pastebin.com/m0mR7VWz

I pasted it to the pastebin not to make this thread to cramped up with text...

After reading the error, first thing that came to my mind was that the picturebox on the thread is broken or that the images in the resources folder are corrupted.

However, the person I spoke to about this, claimed that it was his antivirus blocking the resources folder. He disabled his antivirus ran the program again and everything went without any issues.

(I made sure... and checked, he is right - the antivirus fully blocks the resources folder and doesn't allow anything in or out of the folder)

This is what my resources folder contains:

- Images
- .AppSettings files that are used to load in checkbox settings... For example if you select "No checkboxes" it will apply the .AppSettings file, load it, and none of the checkboxes will be selected (this is a pure example)
- One, (DotNetZip).dll file that is used to extract a zip file
- Zip file that contains the files the installer extracts into the desired folder.

Now... I absolutely have NO idea what could be causing such an issue :(

Is there some way to prevent it?

P.S There was no such problem just a month or two ago.

Thank you!

Comment: You say antivirus blocks the Resources folder, if you manually scan it, doesn't it identify the file(s) causing the issue? Is your Installer blacklisted...have you checked VirusTotal?

Comment: Here is what VirusTotal says... https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/5a149a168e8aa285e77b7646c556ad1186b77ae8f64854dcec0a808fe13704a0/analysis/1425355568/

Comment: You see I personally don't have the problem, the guy who does have the problem didn't tell me what Antivirus is recognizing the installer as a virus :/ I will ask him... I will hit you up once he answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was not my resources folder!

The problem was with the theme not being able to load in time because of a huge amount of load settings. I fixed the problem by adding:

```
Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)
Me.Refresh()
```

in the FormLoad which refreshed all the items on the Windows Form and allowed the program to keep from freezing and perform a lot better.